# Sub site name coming as ["Name"column value]

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sub-site

For only some of my subsites, I am not getting the name I assigned. Instead it is coming as ["Name"Column value].

Where do I have to change this and what is the reason?

Thanks

Comment: where you got this [“Name”column value] is it in site name ?

Comment: No, it's not. @M.Qassas I want to check if there's a place where to change the site page's name

Comment: based on my understand : for change site name, go to site settings>  look and feel > Title, description, and logo , for the site page name > go to pages library > edit page properties and edit it's title , please elaborate more if this is not what you need